# Next.JS start-up console message meaning

Tags: next.js

the Next.JS 14 default start-up console message prints below, can someone tell me what does these all means?

```
Driver resolving to DRIVERLESS (on purpose) - driver_operation_handler.ts:52
merchant.ts:178 ... extracting FIRST context for localhost - merchant.ts:178
main.ts:57 content script exiting - main.ts:57
```

ChatGPT, Co-Pilot, Google